# how to filter out a object from a list of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of object,

```
data = [
    {
      Name: "Ronaldo",
      TeamId: "JuventusFC",
      TeamName: "Juventus",
      PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
      PTypeID: "GOAT"
   },
  {
    Name: "Messi",
    TeamId: "BarcaFC",
    TeamName: "Barca",
    PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
    PTypeID: "GOAT"
  }
]
```

I need to get object that matches TeamId "BarcaFC"

I tried,

```
const myTeamId = "BarcaFC"

const getTeamName = this.props.playerList.data.filter((player) => player.TeamId === myTeamId);
```

I also tried,
const getTeamName = this.props.playerList.data.find((player) => player.TeamId === myTeamId);

But I this dint work as expected

Comment: `"BarcaFc"` is not equal to `"BarcaFC"`. Also, `filter` needs a function: for example, `.filter(teamId => teamId === myTeamId)`

Comment: That's not quite how `filter()` works, take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), specifically how the filtering function is passed in.

Comment: This isn't how lists (arrays) are defined in javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: @Amadan I have edited my question'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter function implementation is incorrect. Please check the docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

For your code, this should work:

```
const getTeamName = this.props.playerList.data.filter(el => el.TeamId === myTeamId);
```

it checks each object in the array, and matches the teamId.

**UPDATE** : Added working snippet.
Couple of problems in your data, first data should be an array of objects like `const data = [{},{}]`, instead it is `const data = {{},{}}` in your example above.

Second, `const myTeamId = "BarcaFc"` in your example, but the value in the data list is `BarcaFC`. Please find the working code:

```js
var data= [
    {
      'Name': "Ronaldo",
      TeamId: "JuventusFC",
      TeamName: "Juventus",
      PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
      PTypeID: "GOAT"
   },
  {
    'Name': "Messi",
    TeamId: "BarcaFC",
    TeamName: "Barca",
    PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
    PTypeID: "GOAT"
  }
]

const myTeamId = "BarcaFC"

const myTeamList = data.filter(el => el.TeamId === myTeamId);

console.log(myTeamList)
```

Comment: updated answer highlighting the issues in your codeblock. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
data = [
  {
     Name: "Ronaldo",
     TeamId: "JuventusFC",
     TeamName: "Juventus",
     PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
     PTypeID: "GOAT",
  },
  {
      Name: "Messi",
      TeamId: "BarcaFC",
      TeamName: "Barca",
      PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
      PTypeID: "GOAT",
  },
  {
      Name: "hello",
      TeamId: "BarcaFC",
      TeamName: "world",
      PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf78d",
      PTypeID: "test"
   }
 ]

const myTeamId = "BarcaFC"

const filterObj = (a)=>{
    return (a.TeamId === myTeamId)
}

let obj = data.filter(filterObj)
console.log(obj)
```

OR
if you want list of objects then append all object into list:

```
data = [
{
   Name: "Ronaldo",
   TeamId: "JuventusFC",
   TeamName: "Juventus",
   PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
   PTypeID: "GOAT",
},
{
  Name: "Messi",
  TeamId: "BarcaFC",
  TeamName: "Barca",
  PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf8c7",
  PTypeID: "GOAT",
},
{
  Name: "hello",
  TeamId: "BarcaFC",
  TeamName: "world",
  PId: "4dc0a2d69cc080aaf78d",
  PTypeID: "test"
}
]

const myTeamId = "BarcaFC"

const filterObj = (a)=>{
    return (a.TeamId === myTeamId)
}

const lst = []
lst.push(data.filter(filterObj))

console.log(lst)
```